# converting many line in text area to txt file

Tags: java, netbeans

how can I convert the text area to txt file but with the same format, because I try to convert it to txt file, but the output on the txt file is just a long line instead on many lines just like on the text area.

[image]

here is the output:
[image]

here is my code:

```
private void convertToTxtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    //////not included on the generated datalogs///
    String lastDevice = jLastDevice.getText(); 
    String progname = jProgramName.getText();
    String progRev = jProgramRevision.getText();
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    String boardname = jBoardname.getText();
    String pn = jPN.getText();
    String sn = jSN.getText();
    String boardrev = jBoardRev.getText();
    String verifStatus = jVerificationStatus.getText();
    String failedTNum = jFailedTNum.getText();
    String checker = jFailingChecker.getText();
    String tester = jTesterNumber.getText();
    String remarks = jRemarks.getText();
    String verifiedBy = jVerifiedBy.getText();
    //String dLogs = jDatalog.getText();

     try{
            File file = new File("\\\\ets88-spare\\e\\Data Logs\\ " + sn + "_" + verifStatus + ".txt");
            if(!file.exists()){
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("Board Name                : " + boardname);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Part Number               : " + pn);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Serial Number             : " + sn);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Board Revision            : " + boardrev);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Failing Test Parameter    : " + failedTNum);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Failing Checker           : " + checker);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Verified By               : " + verifiedBy);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Remakrs                   : " + remarks);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("Tester Number             : " + tester);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("**************************************************************************************");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("*                                    Datalog                                         *");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.write("**************************************************************************************");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.newLine();
            for (String dLogs : jDatalog.getText().split("\\n")){ 
            bw.write(dLogs);
            System.out.println(dLogs);
            }
            bw.close();
            String note = boardname.concat(" with ").concat(sn).concat(" is located on 'ETS88-spare'\'E:'\'Data Logs'"); //" with " + sn " is located on 'EData Logs'"
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, note);
            //System.out.println(note);
        }catch(IOException | HeadlessException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }


}
```

Comment: Just use the JTextArea's own writer as this will convert new lines to OS-specific new line chars in the text file.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I try to use jtextarea's own writer but the output is the same, but when I use the System.out.println(); i got the output that I expected not the same when it is converted to .txt file.

Comment: You don't show your code, so impossible to say what you're doing wrong. For all we know you could still be writing only with `bw.write(dLogs);` within a for loop -- code which obviously will not write any new line chars to the text file. I'm surprised that you didn't simply add a `bw.newLine()` within that same for loop in the original code (any explanation for that omission?).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, ohhh!! I overlook that bw.newLine(); after the bw.write(dLogs);, now its working fine after inserting bw.newLine(); on the code...tnx a lot..